# xslt 1.0 string replace function

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a string "aa::bb::aa"

and need to turn it in to "aa, bb, aa"

I have tried

```
translate(string,':',', ')
```

but this returns "aa,,bb,,aa"

How can this be done.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**A very simple solution (that will work as long as your string value doesn't have spaces):**

```
translate(normalize-space(translate('aa::bb::cc',':',' ')),' ',',')
```

1. translate ":' into " "
2. `normalize-space()` to collapse multiple whitespace characters into a single space " "
3. translate single spaces " " into ","

**A more robust solution would be to use a [recursive template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/replace.html#d8766e61):**

```
<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

**You can use it like this:**

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'aa::bb::cc'"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'::'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="','"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this

Syntax:- `fn:tokenize(string,pattern)`

Example: `tokenize("XPath is fun", "\s+")`
Result: ("XPath", "is", "fun")

Comment: This question is tagged as XSLT 1.0. Your answer requires XSLT 2.0.