# How do i transport XSL data out of the scope of the select?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

When i'm trying to process data out of an xml file I'm facing this problem:
I cant find a way to append the data from the for- each statement.I would like to send them as parameters to the js function.

Here is sample of the xml:

```
 <events>
<event>
    <eventType>some type</eventType>
    <date>12/24/1999</date>
    <participants>
        <participant>
            <participant_name>Mike</participant_name>
        </participant>
        <participant>
            <participant_name>John</participant_name>
        </participant>
    </participants>
```

.
.
.

and here is the xsl file:

```
<xsl:for-each select="event">

<tr>                    

    <xsl:variable name="eventType"select="eventType"> </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="date" select="date"></xsl:variable>

    <td>    
        <xsl:value-of select="$eventType" />    
    </td>

    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$date" /> 
    </td>

    <xsl:for-each select="participants/participant">
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="participant_name"/>   
    </td>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <td>
        <button type="button" onClick="myFunc('{$date} {$eventType}')">

    </td>

    </tr>
```

My goal is to create a table when the last column will be a button which sends all the row parameters to js function.The code above is working fine, but I don't seem to find a way to append the participant_name because of its scope. I searched for a solution and didn't find it. hope to find help here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close - you are already in scope of `participant`, so you just need to navigate down to `participant_name`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="participants/participant">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="participant_name" />
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Edit**

I've just re-read your question and I believe I missed the part about sending to your javascript function? If so, you can build up the participants in another `<xsl:variable>`

```
<xsl:variable name="participants">
  <xsl:for-each select="participants/participant">
     <xsl:value-of select="participant_name" />
    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<button type="button" onClick="myFunc('{$date} {$eventType} {$participants}')" />
```

Last Comma removal [courtesy of here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798269/xslt-concat-string-remove-last-comma)

Comment: Sorry, now it is the correct code. the code is fine as it is.
the issue is how do I transfer the particpant_name like I did in the other element's data to myFunc()

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Its working in terms of the js function. But do I have a way to display the prticipant_name in the columns? I mean to add <td> </td> inside that code block?

Comment: You might want to include the desired output HTML to your question. And *please*, indent your XSLT code properly.

Comment: There seem to be two distinct requirements here 1) Emit a list of td's and 2) Create a comma separated list for the js Function.  Assuming you don't want the `<td>` passed to javascript, you would need to repeat the `<xsl:for-each select="participants/participant">` bit and include a `td` wrapper around each participant which was omitted? One other thing worth mentioning is that we'll also need to [escape out single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711654/xslt-replace-single-quotes-by) in the participant's names for your js function (e.g. to accomodate names like `O'Hara`)