# XSLT for cleaning data

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I intend to use XSLT to clean some unwanted symbols from the following data:

```
<Cart>
    <Row>
        <Ld>Restaurant/Cafe Bar &amp; Stores J-K,3</Ld>
        <Ln>Restaurant/Cafe Bar &amp; Stores J-K</Ln>
    </Row>
</Cart>
```

How can the following symbols be deleted

```
&amp;
/
```

the resulting data would be

```
<Cart>
    <Row>
        <Ld>Restaurant,Cafe Bar, Stores J-K,3</Ld>
        <Ln>Restaurant, Cafe Bar, Stores J-K</Ln>
    </Row>
</Cart>
```

Comment: lee, It seems to me that by "clean" you don't exactly mean "delete". For example, do you want the result to contain "RestaurantCafe", or "Restaurant Cafe" or "Restaurant-Cafe", or ... ? Except for the first case, in all remaining cases you actually need to *replace*. Please, to avoid this confusion, edit the question and provide the exact wanted result (it is a good rule to know that if you haven't provided the exact wanted result in *any* question, then the question isn't well-defined).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [translate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function:

Applied to an identity transform to replace those characters with a `,`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*| node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&amp;/', ',,')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

With XSLT/XPath 2.0 you can use the [replace()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function, which provides a more robust capability for find/replace operations and normalization of leading/trailing whitespace, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*| node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s?(&amp;|/)\s?', ', ')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @ Mads Hansen, can it be replaced with a space or a comma? because the values close up, especially the ones with '/'

Comment: That's pretty easy, just replace the `''` with `'  '` (two spaces) in that translate call, replacing them with spaces rather than nothing.

Comment: Another XSLT 1.0 solution would be a recursive template where you could provide the string that you want to find and what to replace it with. It would make it easier to replace ` &amp; ` with `, `. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7523245/14419

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [replace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function.