# Reading breaks in XML file when using CDATA and XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to read a line break when using `CDATA` but with little luck. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I keep getting:

`This Picture was created by <br /> Type-Style back in 2007.` as the output, the line break is not recognised at allm

**XML**

```
<s xmlns:b="http://crownpublishing.com/imprint/crown-business/">
    <b:bio>
        <b:about>
        <![CDATA[This Picture was created by <br /> Type-Style back in 2007. ]]>
        </b:about>
    </b:bio>
</s>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:b="http://crownpublishing.com/imprint/crown-business/" version="1.0">
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="about"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="s/b:bio/b:about"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Should the output also be a CDATA section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you cannot change the input document. Use string replacement to transform the `br` string into an actual line break. With XSLT 1.0, the standard way of doing string replacement is by writing a *recursive template*.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

The named template is shamelessly stolen from Mads' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7523245/1987598) which in turn borrows from [Dave Pawson](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/replace.html#d8770e43).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:b="http://crownpublishing.com/imprint/crown-business/" version="1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="b">

    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/s/b:bio/b:about"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&lt;br /&gt;'" />
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'&#10;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
        This Picture was created by 
 Type-Style back in 2007. 
        </result>
```

Try this solution [online here](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtu/2).

Answer (score 1):

A literal newline in your source document will carry through to the output. Try:

```
<s xmlns:b="http://crownpublishing.com/imprint/crown-business/">
    <b:bio>
        <b:about>
        <![CDATA[This Picture was created by
Type-Style back in 2007. ]]>
        </b:about>
    </b:bio>
</s>
```

`<br />` doesn't have any special meaning in XML. On the other hand, if you intend to be producing XHTML as output then what you've got only makes sense in a browser, and there it should appear as a newline.