# Replace String dynamically XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am facing an issue where I have to replace string dynamically in loop. I have to convert an XML into HTML.

XML Structure is:

```
<FUNCTION ID="XYZ" UNIT_TYPE="percent"/>   
    <STRING_LITERAL><![CDATA[1143]]></STRING_LITERAL>
    <STRING_LITERAL><![CDATA[1]]></STRING_LITERAL>                                               
    <STRING_LITERAL>NULL</STRING_LITERAL>
    <STRING_LITERAL>NULL</STRING_LITERAL>
    <STRING_LITERAL><![CDATA[Prepaid]]></STRING_LITERAL> 
    <STRING_LITERAL>NULL</STRING_LITERAL>
    <BOOLEAN>true</BOOLEAN>
    <BOOLEAN>true</BOOLEAN>
    <STRING_LITERAL>NULL</STRING_LITERAL>
    <STRING_LITERAL>NULL</STRING_LITERAL>
    <STRING_LITERAL>NULL</STRING_LITERAL>
    <STRING_LITERAL>NULL</STRING_LITERAL>
</FUNCTION>
```

The HTML output expected is:

```
Scheme : 1143
Payout : 1
Deposit: Prepaid

Target : true
Is Reprotable : true
```

I checked the solution at : [xslt 1.0 string replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520762/xslt-1-0-string-replace-function) but I am unable to apply it in this case. Please help.

Comment: This is not at all clear. Please show the valid input XML and expected output.

Comment: Like what? Please [edit] your post and include both input and output XML

Comment: my code will produce output like:
 Generic Attibute1    Value1
 Generic Attribute2   Value2
 Generic Attribute3   Value3
 
 But i need values to be displayed as: 
 Generic Attribute1 Scheme
 Generic Attribute2 Payout
 Generic Attribute3 Deposit
 
 and so on...

Comment: STILL NOT CLEAR.  [EDIT] YOUR POST AND PROVIDE INPUT AND OUTPUT XML.

Comment: The expected output posted is not HTML, that's just plain text...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear about what you're trying to do. But a very simple XSLT 1.0 to generate your expected output from the input you posted could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FUNCTION">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Scheme : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="STRING_LITERAL[1]"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:text>Payout : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="STRING_LITERAL[2]"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:text>Deposit : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="STRING_LITERAL[5]"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Target : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="BOOLEAN[1]"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:text>Is Reprotable : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="BOOLEAN[2]"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```