# How to insert a space before and after a specific character in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to insert a space before and after a specific character?

I have:

```
<g:product_type><![CDATA[Lorem>ipsum>dolor]]></g:product_type>
```

and I want this:

```
<g:product_type><![CDATA[Lorem > ipsum > dolor]]></g:product_type>
```

I want insert space between every  ">"

Comment: Can you say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: You could use a recursive template here to do the replace. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520762/xslt-1-0-string-replace-function as one example.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!