# Replace ASCII whitespace with non breaking space(&nbsp;) in a node's text in XSLT

Tags: string, xslt, replace, xslt-1.0

String inside a node is like this

```
<fo:myblock>     This is       Text      </fo:myblock>
```

i want to replace those ASCII white-space with `&nbsp:` or `&#160;` 
i have to do it in XSLT. Any ideas for this.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous - please show the exact output you expect to get in the given example.

Comment: Did you look at the various white-space options in xsl-fo [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#white-space-treatment) or [white-space-collapse](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#white-space-collapse) or [wrap-option](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#wrap-option)? You might be able to get what you need out-of-the-box

Comment: Look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520762/xslt-1-0-string-replace-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520762/xslt-1-0-string-replace-function).