# Translate functions in xslt

Tags: xslt

Am having a code like this to translate from `&amp;amp;` to `&amp;` which is working fine, but it also removing other characters in the field which is `a`,`m`,`p` because we are translating.
I just want this to work to translate `&amp;amp;` to `&amp;` not to delete `a`,`m`,`p` characters.

```
<xsl:when 
test="contains(//column[@name=&quot;Description&quot;]/text(), &quot;&amp;amp;&quot;)">
<xsl:value-of
select="translate(//column[@name=&quot;Description&quot;]/text(),'&amp;amp;','&amp; ')" 
disable-output-escaping="no"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Input: Input: `&amp;amp;wUS &amp;amp;and  amptestamp`

Current Output: `&amp;wUS  &amp;nd   test`

Expected output: `&amp;wUS &amp;and  amptestamp`

Comment: <xsl:when test="contains(//column[@name=&quot;Description&quot;]/text(), &quot;&amp;amp;&quot;)">
<xsl:value-of select="translate(//column[@name=&quot;Description&quot;]/text(),'&amp;amp;','&amp; ')" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
</xsl:when>

Comment: Use the built in replace() function.See http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_replace.html

Comment: replace function will work in XSLT1.0?

Comment: Nope. But in this case just look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520762/xslt-1-0-string-replace-function
There is a solution for it already.

Comment: Is the input you have shown (`&amp;wUS &amp;and amptestamp`) part of an XML document? Is the output you want (`&wUS &and amptestamp`) also part of an XML or HTML document or is that plain text? In XML the ampersand is escaped as `&amp;` but of course as long as you use XML tools to read out data you will get or be able to get a plain `&`.

Comment: What is your code? And what XSLT version are you using? This doesn't sound like a job for the translate() function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xslt 1.0 string replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520762/xslt-1-0-string-replace-function)